# Testing symfony 2 forms

Tags: forms, unit-testing, testing, symfony, symfony-forms

I develop new type, but I don't know how I can test it.
Assert annotation is not load and validations is not called.
Could any one please help me?

```
class BarcodeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->
            add('price');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundles\MyBundle\Form\Model\Barcode',
            'intention'  => 'enable_barcode',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'enable_barcode';
    }
}
```

A have following model for storing form data.

```
namepspace Bundles\MyBundle\Form\Model;
class Barcode
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = "100",
     *      max = "100000",
     *      minMessage = "...",
     *      maxMessage = "..."
     * )
     */
    public $price;
}
```

I develop some test like this, the form didn't get valid data but it is valid! (Because annotation is not applied)
I try adding ValidatorExtension but I dont know how can I set constructor paramaters

```
    function test...()
    {
        $field = $this->factory->createNamed('name', 'barcode');
        $field->bind(
                array(
                    'price'         => 'hello',
        ));

        $data = $field->getData(); 

        $this->assertTrue($field->isValid()); // Must not be valid 

    }
```

Comment: Documentation says : 
"Don't test the validation: it is applied by a listener that is not active in the test case and it relies on validation configuration. Instead, unit test your custom constraints directly."

see http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/unit_testing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need to unit-test the form. Cant You unit test validation of Your entity and cover controller with your expected output?
While testing validation of entity You could use something like this:

```
public function testIncorrectValuesOfUsernameWhileCallingValidation()
{
  $v =  \Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorFactory::buildDefault();
  $validator = $v->getValidator();

  $not_valid = array(
    'as', '1234567890_234567890_234567890_234567890_dadadwadwad231',
    "tab\t", "newline\n",
    "Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn hasn't happened to ", 'trśżź',
    'semicolon;', 'quote"', 'tick\'', 'backtick`', 'percent%', 'plus+', 'space ', 'mich @l'
  );    

  foreach ($not_valid as $key) {
    $violations = $validator->validatePropertyValue("\Brillante\SampleBundle\Entity\User", "username", $key);
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, count($violations) ,"dissalow username to be ($key)");
  }
```

}

Comment: I didn't know the technical solution for testing type like that, as mentioned it earlier, so I asked question.
As you said, Must I generate controller and build this type in it, and then test the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Functional test. Given that you generate a CRUD with app/console doctrine:generate:crud with routing=/ss/barcode, and given that maxMessage="Too high" you can:

```
class BarcodeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testValidator()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/ss/barcode/new');
        $this->assertTrue(200 === $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        // Fill in the form and submit it
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
            'ss_bundle_eavbundle_barcodetype[price]'  => '12',
        ));

        $client->submit($form);
        $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
        // Check data in the show view
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('td:contains("12")')->count() > 0);

        // Edit the entity
        $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link());
        /* force validator response: */ 
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Edit')->form(array(
            'ss_bundle_eavbundle_barcodetype[price]'  => '1002',
        ));

        $crawler = $client->submit($form);
        // Check the element contains the maxMessage:
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('ul li:contains("Too high")')->count() > 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Albreto.
But my data will not be saved in database, I will call service, then.
I don't know, this is technical solution!? I think crawling the page, make test slower. what is you solution!?

Answer (score -1):

Include this line must be in Model and try it after include look like your model.

```
/* Include the required validators */
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

namespace Bundles\MyBundle\Form\Model;
class Barcode
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = "100",
     *      max = "100000",
     *      minMessage = "min message here",
     *      maxMessage = "max message here"
     * )
     */
    public $price;
}
```